# Select column from another table if it matches a content

Tags: mysql, select

I've a SELECT which checks a status of active alarms (icinga).
This select joins different tables and until here all ok.
On the result I've as value/column an object_id as well. I would like to add a column to that select that could be empty or not, because, searching that 'object_id' on a different table, I could get a value or not. This accessory table is structured having: `object_id`, `varname`, `varvalue`.
So, i.e., my SELECT returns those values:

```
`name`, `object_id`, `status`
`Hello`, `123456`, `OK`
```

I would add the column `City` that should compared to a table having:

```
`object_id`, `varname`, `varvalue`
`123456`, `city`, `Rome`
`123456`, `lake`, `Garda`
`789789`, `city`, `Milano`
```

So that if the second table has `object_id` = `123456` AND `city` = `Rome` the result should be:

```
`name`, `object_id`, `status`, `city`
`Hello`, `123456`, `OK`, `Rome`
```

Otherwise the result should be:

```
`Hello`, `123456`, `OK`, `UNKNOWN`
```

How to do that?

Hope I've explained it well :-)

Thanks!

*** EDIT ***

It's better I explain with real example. My query actually is the following:

```
select icinga_objects.object_id, icinga_objects.name1 as host_name, icinga_objects.name2 as ServiceName, "service" as Type, icinga_servicestatus.last_check as LastCheckTime, icinga_servicestatus.last_hard_state_change as LastStateChange, TIMEDIFF(now(), icinga_servicestatus.last_hard_state_change) AS SinceTime,
CASE
    WHEN icinga_servicestatus.current_state = 0 THEN '0'
    WHEN icinga_servicestatus.current_state = 1 THEN '2'
    WHEN icinga_servicestatus.current_state = 2 THEN '3'
    ELSE  '3'
END AS state
FROM icinga_objects, icinga_servicestatus, icinga_services WHERE icinga_servicestatus.service_object_id IN
  (SELECT service_object_id FROM icinga_services WHERE icinga_services.host_object_id IN
    (SELECT host_object_id FROM icinga_hostgroup_members WHERE hostgroup_id IN
      (SELECT hostgroup_id FROM icinga_hostgroups WHERE alias = 'MY-HOSTGROUP-TO-FILTER')
     )
  )
AND icinga_servicestatus.service_object_id NOT IN 
  (SELECT service_object_id FROM icinga_services WHERE icinga_services.service_object_id IN (
     SELECT object_id FROM icinga_objects WHERE icinga_objects.is_active = 1 AND icinga_objects.object_id IN
       (SELECT object_id FROM icinga_customvariables WHERE varvalue = '8x5')
     )
  )
AND icinga_servicestatus.last_check > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR
AND icinga_servicestatus.state_type = 1
AND icinga_servicestatus.scheduled_downtime_depth = 0
AND icinga_objects.object_id = icinga_services.service_object_id
AND icinga_servicestatus.service_object_id = icinga_services.service_object_id
AND icinga_servicestatus.current_state = 2
AND icinga_servicestatus.problem_has_been_acknowledged = 0
```

This gives me as result, in example:

```
`object_id`, `host_name`, `ServiceName`, `Type`, `LastCheckTime`, `LastStateChange`, `SinceTime`, `State`
`123456`, `myHostName`, `myServiceName`, `service`, `2020-04-29 17:19:21`, `2020-04-28 14:50:27`, `26:32:51`, `3`
```

Here I would like to add the column.
So, now if I search `object_id` into `icinga_customvariables` I *could* find entries, or not. In Example, searching `object_id` = `123456` I have 4 records, but ONLY one having `varname` = `NAME_IM_SEARCHING` and so I need to add to the above result the corresponding of `varvalue` searching `icinga_customvariables`.`object_id` = '123456' AND `varname` = `NAME_IM_SEARCHING`. IF there are NO results, then the added cloumn should be `UNKNOWN`, otherwise the added column should be = `icinga_customvariables`.`varvalue`.

How to add it? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place your query into a "table expression" so it becomes simpler to join it to the `other_table`. For example:

```
select
  q.*,
  coalesce(o.varvalue, 'UNKNOWN') as city
from (
  -- your existing query here
) q
left join other_table o on o.object_id = q.object_id and o.varname = 'city'
```

**EDIT: Joining multiple times**

As requested if you need to extract more city names using another column, or if you want to extract against another table altogether, you can add an extra `LEFT JOIN`. For example:

```
select
  q.*,
  coalesce(o.varvalue, 'UNKNOWN') as city,
  coalesce(o2.varvalue, 'UNKNOWN') as lake
from (
  -- your existing query here
) q
left join other_table o on o.object_id = q.object_id and o.varname = 'city'
left join other_table o2 on o.object_id = q.object_id and o2.varname = 'lake'
```

Comment: Hello, added real example to be more precise, thanks!

Comment: Hello @the-impaler Thanks, I was able adding a column in my select `icinga_objects.object_id` to then compare like you suggested and it works. What if I would like to do the same twice? I mean, I then need to add a second colum and extract `o.varvalue` but based on a different `o.varname`, always matching the same `o.object_it`. So in that case we would have two `o.object_it` with same id and two different `o.varname`.  Ideas? THANKS

Comment: @Simon I added an extra example of retrieving a second value. With this strategy you can compute more columns as needed.